# Object reference lost in HTML service

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm developing an application with HTML service and I want to use the Module Pattern.

I don't know why the functions inside the function are losing the reference to the object. I don't know if this is a google apps script server call related problem or a general javascript one.

Could someone help me to find the problem? Here is the code.

```
var Handshake = (function () {

var self = this;
var contacts; 

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(parse).withUserObject(this).withFailureHandler(onFailure).getContacts();
    console.log("JUST CALLED GET CONTACTS");


function parse (JSONstring,parent)
{
   parent.contacts = JSON.parse(JSONstring);
   console.log ("Parsed info "+JSON.stringify(parent));
}


return {

    contacts : contacts
}

}());
```

Seems that Guillaume found the problem, but I don't understand why the object behaves like this.

*If you make it even more generic, and I launch it from a commandLine, this is what I get:*

```
var Handshake = (function () {

var self = this,contacts,parse; 

parse = function (JSONstring,parent)
{
   console.log(this);
   this.contacts = JSON.parse(JSONstring);
   console.log ("Parsed info "+JSON.stringify(this));
};

console.log("Undefined handshake?"+this);
console.log("JUST CALLED GET CONTACTS");

return {

    contacts : contacts, parse:parse
};

}());
```

Output:

```
Undefined handshake?[object Window]
```

---

**EDIT**
Finally I found the problem.
As Guillaume pointed, ***this*** was pointing to the window object. I think I should check again how object works. Moving the google script call into a function fixed this problem.

Here is the function:

```
init = function() {

console.log("Undefined handshake?"+JSON.stringify(this));
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(parse).withUserObject(this).withFailureHandler(onFailure).getContacts();
console.log("JUST CALLED GET CONTACTS");

};
```

If someone would like to explain me why this is the correct approach I will be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe you lose the object ref, which seems (without knowing more about the call context ) to be root windows object when calling google.script.

Have you tried to use your function as :

```
var parent = .. ; // myContextObject which will be used as 'this'
var HandshakeFn = function(){..};
var Handshake = HandshakeFn.call(parent);
```

To clarify the answer, every function call in javascript is owned by an object (the context), which is default as window (the root).
When you call the Handshake function as you have done using

```
Handshake = (function(){...})();
```

the context 'this' is the object from where it has been called. 
Because you call your function directly from the root, any reference to 'this' in the function will return a ref to the window.

To avoid this behavior, you may explicitly set the calling context using

```
HandshakeFn.call(myobject);
```

With that, 'this' will refer to myobject instead of window. And when you set the user object to googlescript it will return the proper object in the second 'parent" parameters.

What i suggest here is to avoid dealing with the context and second parameter with google script

```
var Handshake = (function () {

var self = {}; // you need to explicitely create an object here !

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(parse).withFailureHandler(onFailure).getContacts();
console.log("JUST CALLED GET CONTACTS");


function parse (JSONstring)
{
   self.contacts = JSON.parse(JSONstring);
   console.log ("Parsed info "+JSON.stringify(self));
}

return self;

}());
```

Do not forget to vote if you find this useful.

P.S. : Sorry for my poor English, it is not my native language.

regards.

Comment: Hello Guillaume. Thanks for your help. I don't understand at all your answer. The goal is the object fills itself with an asynchronous call to google server. The problem is at EVERY point this is always undefined. If I try console.log(this) inside the object or inside any function of the object I get undefined. I would like to avoid global variables, that's why I'm using the module pattern. Are you suggesting me to split the object into several parts? Can you expand it a little bit? Thank you.

Comment: Havent seen it too deeply but Guillaume seems correct. The part about not getting the right "this" is independent of apps script, its just how javascript is defined to be. like you defined it, handshake is just assigned to be a function. You want it to be an object containing the function as a property, like Guillaume pointed out by doing handshake.somefuncion(), only then will somefunction find "this" to be "handshake". As per why you get undefined instead of window, might be because of the "caja" code that boxes apps script and might prevent you from getting at some stuff.